# Can we store the address on an Array in another array's index?

Tags: java

I want to store the address of an array in another array's index. Is this possible?

PS: I am trying this in JAVA

```
int[] First;
int[] Second;

Second[0]=First;
```

Comment: The element of an `int[]` is an integer, 32 bit  - nothing else. `First` is an array of such integers. That's it. Java doesn't feature "addresses".

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible,because
First is array of integers, you can't store array of integers in an int:

```
Type mismatch 
cannot convert from int[] to int
```

Answer (score 0):

Well technically there's a way to get the address of a field or an object in Java using Unsafe API as mentioned [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/address-of-a-java-object/) but you should never rely on that for two reasons

1. Unsafe might be going away in future versions.
2. More importantly you cannot rely on the address you got using any
   means. As part of Garbage Collection, objects are moved between
   regions (or) even re-arranged within a region during compaction
   phase, so the address you have might be stale and the actual object
   might have been moved to somewhere else.

If you really want to store an int[] in another array, you need to use int[][] something like this

```
int[] i1 = {1,2,3,4};
int[] i2 = {3,24,33,41};
int[][] main = {i1,i2};
```

Comment: @Arkantos Thanks! I was thinking of mentioning the Unsafe API, but I figured that it might not be what they actually wanted.

Comment: Yes, In fact your answer is pretty straight forward as to how to do it reliably. I just added reason as to why he should not rely on addresses even if he finds some other means to do it :)